# Access violation writing locations 0x0000000a

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I have made a simple program in which I execute a program with arguments which the User inputs, but whenever I run it, it gives me the error

```
        "Unhandled exception at 0x00f138b7 in SZP_Client.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000a."
```

My code is

```
        char* command_text;
        cout << "Enter SERVER IP Address without Port ";
        cin >> command_text;
        char* command_str = strdup("PServLib.exe \"127.0.0.1\" \"30760\" ");
        string command_string_out_final= command_str;
        command_string_out_final.append(command_text);
        command_string_out_final = command_string_out_final + " \"3627\"";
        system(command_string_out_final.c_str());
```

Why is my code throwing an Access Violation, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What does the backtrace say?

Comment: what is the backtrace? srry, I'm a noob... in visual studio 2010 how would I find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The culprit is `cin >> command_text`. When writing to a `char*` it assumes this is a char array large enough to hold the value being written. Instead it's an uninitialized `char*`, so you're writing into arbitrary memory.

The simplest fix is to change `command_text` into a `std::string`.

Answer (score 4):

```
char* command_text;
cout << "Enter SERVER IP Address without Port ";
cin >> command_text;
```

`command_text` is an unintialized pointer. Why are you mixing `char*` and `std::string` in your code ? Just use `std::string` everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

```
char* command_text;

cin >> command_text;
```

This is reading into a C style string that has no space allocated for it.

It would work much better using a C++ string

```
std::string command_text;
cin >> command_text;
```

which allocates space as needed to store the input.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want

```
        string command_text;
```

rather than a `char *`.  `cin` will try to put it's output into a `string`, rather than a `char*`.